# Object is possibly "undefined" при попытке перебора массива

Tags: reactjs, typescript, интерфейс

При попытке перебора массива вылетает ошибка:

> Object is possibly "undefined".

Предоставляю код:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface ItemsProps {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface ItemsArrProps {
  arr: ItemsProps[];
}

export const AppOne = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemsArrProps>();
  return <div>{items.map((item) => item)}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть код приложили, тут нет гадалок.

Comment: Благодарю! Разве мой код не отображается?

Comment: export const AppOne = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState<ItemsArrProps>();

    return (
      <div>
        {items.arr.map(a => `${a.id} - ${a.name}`)}
      </div>
    );
  };

У меня нет ошибок.

Comment: У меня в переборе после items сразу вызываю метод map. Я уже остранил эту ошибку. В любом случае благодарю!

Comment: `useState<ItemsArrProps>()` вы не задаете начальное значение `items`, поэтому possible undefined. Сделайте `useState<ItemsArrProps>([])` хотя бы

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!